# How was this question title not rejected by the software?

Tags: discussion

I was in SOCVR and this question popped up:

[#$%%^^&&***(()(@09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753443/09)

I was just curious how the system didn't reject this title as being obvious symbol spam. I had assumed that Stack Overflow had a system in place to attempt to detect spam/symbol spam in titles, and this title is around 90% symbols.

My question is, why was this not rejected by the system? What protection does Stack Overflow have in place for similar titles? What can we do to make this system more efficient (Or is there even actually beneficial to?)

Comment: That's a MAJOR whack-a-mole regex game. Block "problem", people will write "problematic", or "problenatic". Preventing EVERYTHING isn't necessarily the best of ideas.

Comment: @Patrice I know, I'm talking specifically about symbol spam. Why not just check if the title consists of mainly symbols and block it if it does?

Comment: What percentage of bad questions have titles that are entirely symbols?  That's the first one I've ever seen.  The automated quality tools are looking for the things very likely to be in bad quesitons, not every possible bad title that people don't actually use in practice.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Why write that code just because of *one* bad question?

Comment: @Servy that was part of my question. Asking if it is even beneficial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When it comes to users writing bad titles for their questions, you can pretty much throw them into two separate buckets:

1. Users who are legitimately having trouble writing their question.
2. Users who just made no attempt whatsoever to write a good question.

Users in the first group can usually be helped by warning or outright blocking on specific keywords that frequently indicate bad questions and providing some guidance. Heck, [Code Review has a list of such phrases](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/code-review-clippy) based on some analysis of frequent pitfalls users face there.

Users in the second group, though, are kinda hopeless. The user clearly made no attempt to create a proper title there, and there's just no guidance we could possibly give for that title. Outright blocking it would likely just cause them to do something else that bypasses it without much effort. In those cases, blocking serves little purpose other than to make crappy titles a bit more complicated so they are harder to weed out. So all we'd really be doing is expending development effort to make it *harder* for users to quickly notice terrible questions and close them down.

It's worth the effort to block/warn users who fall into the first group, but mostly a waste of effort to do anything to block users in the second group.

Comment: Indeed, it may even have not ended up in SOCVR like it had now. Who knows, it may have just survived for a very long time. The site's best protection mechanism is still it's user base with it's very efficient eyes, brains and button mashing fingers.